# Build URI in Spring MVC with optional uri template variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to build a URI from a Spring UriTemplate where the last uri variable is optional:

```
new UriTemplate("/test/{id}").expand("1")   // OK
```

should expand to `/test/1`, whereas

```
new UriTemplate("/test/{id}").expand()      // fails
```

should simply expand to `/test/`.

Unfortunately I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'id'` in the second case.

Is there a way to tell Spring, that the uri variable is optional?

**UPDATE**

Just passing in `null` doesn't work in my case, because expanding the template is happening inside a small library base class, where I don't know the exact URI template and the number of URI variables upfront.

The (simplified) use case is as follows:

```
void post(Object... uriVars) {
  var url = new UriTemplate(template()).expand().toString();
  // do stuff with the url
}

protected abstract template();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be rather an edge case, but I'll answer my own question. Just in case somebody else might need this.

I solved this by copying the URI variables to an array of the expected size:

```
void post(Object... uriVars) {
  var uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(template());
  var totalNumberOfVars = uriTemplate.getVariableNames().size();
  var uri uriTemplate.expand(Arrays.copyOf(uriVars, totalNumberOfVars));
  // do stuff with the url
}

protected abstract template();
```

It no ain't pretty, but it works.